# swift dictionary is returning nil

Tags: swift, swift2

```
let countryCodes = NSLocale.ISOCountryCodes()

for countryCode in countryCodes {
    let dictionary = NSDictionary(object: countryCode, forKey: NSLocaleCountryCode)

    if let aValue = dictionary[countryCode] {
        print("country code of \(countryCode) is \(aValue)")
        }
```

The print function never gets executed. However, if I remove the if `let`, I can get `countryCode` printed but not `aValue`, it will always return `nil`.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are mixing key and object, do that instead :

```
if let aValue = dictionary[NSLocaleCountryCode] {

            print("country code of \(countryCode) is \(aValue)")
        }
```

Comment: wow, thanks. I'm not to used to initObjectForKey dictionaries. learned my lesson I guess.